# How to access git release number within code

Tags: git, github

I have a Python GUI on Github that is versioned using the Github release system.  I would like to make the release number available to users within the software.  Is this information stored in a way that I can access it programmatically?

Currently, we store the version number in a version file which can be accessed from the GUI, but this is prone to getting overlooked and so it is sometimes out-of-date.  Is there a different best practice that doesn't require keeping track of the version number in two separate places?

Comment: Since the question is related to python and project releases on github, this could be useful: https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the latest release number, if you are using the [Github release system](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/), there is an [API for it](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/). You want to [get the latest release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-the-latest-release) which should be `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest`.

However, you want what version number the particular release the user is using is, not what the latest on Github happens to be.  For that you do need the release number somewhere in the software.

I would recommend putting it in a configuration file, something easily read and edited by software.  Then your ***automated*** release program will edit that config file and do everything else involved in making a release.  It is very important that the release process is fully automated else, as you've observed, people will forget things.

To the release manager it would probably look something like this:

```
make_release v1.2.3 master
```

This would do everything.  Edit the config.  Run release tests.  Commit changes.  Create a release on Github.  Etc...

If you're using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) you wouldn't even let the human decide on the version number.  The human would just say what type of release it is.

```
# v1.2.3 -> v1.2.4
make_release --patch master

# v1.2.3 -> v1.3.0
make_release --minor master
```

Comment: Minor release from v1.2.3 would go to v1.3.0 instead of v1.3.3: _"Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented."_

Comment: @1615903 Thanks, fixed!